# How portable is Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

If I take the hard drive out of the existing pc and install it in the newer one will it boot up okay?  Will it automatically detect and load the drivers for the new hardware?

Comment: Yes this works flawlessly. I have hotswapped(thats the term for it) between a Dell Inspiron 6400 and a Lenovo Thinkpad R61. The dell had nvidia drivers, which were automatically disabled on the Thinkpad.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Even if it was not a SATA interface you'd be fine.

1 thing you need to do: delete any 3rd party drivers before taking out your hard disk. The main one is the video card driver. And also delete the NIC 3rd party driver if you are using one currently.

Ubuntu will reset all drivers during booting and will use those that are needed for your system. After booting upgrade the video card driver if you want the 3rd party one.

Comment: I don't suppose there is a quick and easy way to identify and delete the 3rd party drivers?

Comment: @MarkSteele Maybe the Driver Manager application?

Comment: @MarkSteele YES! see "additional drivers"

Answer (score -1):

Delete /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistant-net-rules and reboot to detect your new netwok card (the card has a new nac address)